# Java Regex for the pattern [#d][#h][#m][#s] to specify a time duration, fields are optional but ordered

Tags: java, regex

I am looking for a regex that supports a String of the pattern `[#d][#h][#m][#s]` to specify a time duration, where 'd' for days, 'h' for hours and so on.

Some valid Strings are,
`1h2s`, `1m`, `2m15s`, `2h10s`, etc.

`2m1h`, `2k30s` are Invalid

I have tried the folowing code,

```
String duration = "2d0k15s";

try {
    duration.matches("(\\d+d)?(\\d+h)?(\\d+m)?(\\d+s)?");
    
    System.out.println("Valid.");
} catch (final PatternSyntaxException pse) {
    System.out.println("Not valid! " + pse.getMessage());
}
```

But it says Valid for all inputs. I tried with,
`duration.matches("(\\d+d)?(\\d+h)?(\\d+m)?(\\d+s)?$");`

but, still getting the same result.

**What I need to change in my code to achieve what I'm looking for? Thanks.**

Comment: `matches` doesn't throw an exception when the match fails, that is for regex syntax errors. Use the boolean return value.

Comment: I got it from here that it throws an exception, https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches-java.lang.String- Looks like I need to use Pattern.matches(regex, str)

Comment: Why not just an if else condition!

Comment: basically `if (duration.matches(...)) { /* valid */ } else { /* not valid */ }`

Comment: I think I deserve to know what causes a negative vote! I did my research before I asking here.

Comment: The exception is thrown when the regular expression pattern is invalid, it is not related to whether the test string matches a valid regular expression. For example: `"abc".matches("(")` will throw `PatternSyntaxException: Unclosed group near index 1`

Comment: Why not just do `Duration.parse("PT" + input);`? All your "valid strings" will work fine

Answer (score 1):

Why not just an if..else condition, for example:

```
final String regex = "(\\d+d)?(\\d+h)?(\\d+m)?(\\d+s)?";
String[] durations = {"1h2s", "1m", "2m15s", "2h10s", "2m1h", "2k30s"};

for (String duration : durations) {

    // Just this
    if (duration.matches(regex)) {
        System.out.println("Valid");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Not Valid");
    }

}
```

**Outputs**

```
Valid
Valid
Valid
Valid
Not Valid
Not Valid
```

Comment: I'm interested for the exception message when the string is an invalid one. But thanks, I think I can reach there now. +1.

Comment: Keep in mind, if each group is quantified with a _?_, then an empty value may match.

Answer (score 1):

To preface, your code implies that if the value does not match, the *PatternSyntaxException* will be thrown.
This is not the case; that is for when there is an error within the syntax—e.g., an open group, *"(\d+d"*.

To fix your code, just utilize a conditional statement.
And, in addition to that, you'll want to check if *duration* is not empty.

Since every group here specifies the *optional*, *?*, quantifier, an empty value would match.

```java
String duration = "2d0k15s";
if (!duration.isEmpty() && duration.matches("(\\d+d)?(\\d+h)?(\\d+m)?(\\d+s)?")) {
    System.out.println("Valid.");
} else {
    System.out.println("Not valid!");
}
```

Furthermore, you could check the value with a single regex, although it is somewhat verbose.
You'll need to provide each combination.

Here is the first, generic approach, which doesn't evaluate the numbers.

```
^(?:(?:\d+d)(?:(?:\d+h)?(?:\d+m)?(?:\d+s)?)|(?:\d+h)(?:(?:\d+m)?(?:\d+s)?)|(?:(?:\d+m)(?:\d+s)?)|(?:\d+s))$
```

And, here is the second, which checks for the validity—e.g., not *"24h"*, or *"60m"*, etc..

```
^(?:(?:[1-9]+d)(?:(?:(?:2[0-3]|1\d|[1-9])h)?(?:(?:[1-5]\d|[1-9])m)?(?:(?:[1-5]\d|[1-9])s)?)|(?:(?:2[0-3]|1\d|[1-9])h)(?:(?:(?:[1-5]\d|[1-9])m)?(?:(?:[1-5]\d|[1-9])s)?)|(?:(?:(?:[1-5]\d|[1-9])m)(?:(?:[1-5]\d|[1-9])s)?)|(?:(?:[1-5]\d|[1-9])s))$
```

Finally, here is your original pattern, with the validity checks.

```
(?:[1-9]+d)?(?:(?:2[0-3]|1\d|[1-9])h)?(?:(?:[1-5]\d|[1-9])m)?(?:(?:[1-5]\d|[1-9])s)?
```

Example

```java
String[] strings = {
    "1h2s", "1m", "2m15s", "2h10s",
    "2m1h", "2k30s", "", "0d", "24h", "60m", "60s" };
String regex = "(?:[1-9]+d)?(?:(?:2[0-3]|1\\d|[1-9])h)?(?:(?:[1-5]\\d|[1-9])m)?(?:(?:[1-5]\\d|[1-9])s)?";
boolean valid;
for (String string : strings) {
    valid = !string.isEmpty() && string.matches(regex);
    System.out.printf("%-10s is %s%n", "'%s'".formatted(string), valid ? "valid" : "invalid");
}
```

Output

```
'1h2s'     is valid
'1m'       is valid
'2m15s'    is valid
'2h10s'    is valid
'2m1h'     is invalid
'2k30s'    is invalid
''         is invalid
'0d'       is invalid
'24h'      is invalid
'60m'      is invalid
'60s'      is invalid
```